# Enable/disable Azure Logic App using CLI

Tags: azure-devops, azure-logic-apps, azure-cli

Is it possible to enable/disable an Azure Logic App using the CLI? I didn't find anything about it in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest).

There's a way to do it via the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/Workflows/Disable), which requires creating an access token. However, since I'm running from my shell or from VSTS (which has a az CLI task), I'm already authorized there so I'd like to simplify this process using the CLI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do it using the following command

```
az resource invoke-action --action disable  --name 'YOURLOGICAPP' -g 'YOURRESOURCEGROUP' --resource-type 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows'
```